# Preload images using an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted write preloader images and I was stuck on the checking already lodead images:

```
var imgContainer = [];

$(this).find('img').each(function() {
    imgContainer.push({
        image: $(this)
        // other properties
    })
});

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(imgContainer[0].image.complete);  // undefined
}, 2000);
```

but this solution worked (without objects in array):

```
var imgContainer = $(this).find('img');

setInterval(function() {
    console.log(imgContainer[0].complete)         // true
}, 2000);
```

Why it's not working?

Comment: `event` sounds like a really bad choice for that argument name. You do know you can use `this` and make the function argument-less?

Comment: Well, those two lines are not identical, is there a complete property of `image`?

Comment: @ThiefMaster You're right. I changed it, but this still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: While `event` is semantically incorrect it was used in the proper way as the second argument in the itterative function passed to the function each on a jQuery collection is the element in question for the relevant iteration.

Comment: As a side note, checking if something loaded with setInterval probably isn't the way to go, but now you know what you did wrong, implement @Engineer s solution instead ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setInterval` ,for checking whether all images are loaded, just replace your above code with this code:

```
(function(that){
    var remains = 0;        
    var loadHandler = function(){
       if(--remains == 0){
          console.log('All images are loaded !!!');
       }   
    };

    $(that).find('img').each(function() {
         if( !this.complete ){
             remains++;
             $(this).load(loadHandler);
         }
    });        
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're trying to access the 'complete' attribute on the jQuery object while it will not have this. Try accessing the complete attribute on the DOM element itself instead.

I believe this code should work better:

```
var imgContainer = [];

$(this).find('img').each(function() {
    imgContainer.push({
        image: $(this)
        // other properties
    })
});

setInterval(function() {
    /* imgContainer = array with objects, [0] = get first element */
    /* image = jQuery collection, [0] = get dom element of the first item in the collection */
    console.log(imgContainer[0].image[0].complete);  
}, 2000);
```